# Best performance to select first 0 - n children of a parent in jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the first n children under a specific parent.  For this case I don't want to use each index unless its the best performance.

Example:

```
// select first 20 child elements
var twentyChildElements = $("div").children("span(20)"); 

<div>
 <span index="1"/>
 <span index="2"/>
 <span index="3"/>
....
 <span index="n"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you run this million times a second?

Comment: It doesn't work.  I want to select the first 20 child elements.

Comment: So you better ask about "any solution that works" then. You see the difference between them? PS: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: Used in an infinitescroller. You are thinking too small. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [jQuery's `slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
var twentyChildElements = $("div").children("span").slice(0, 20);
```

See also [this performance test case](http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-lt-vs-nth-child) - it's always faster than `:lt(n)`, but can be outperformed by native selector engines.

Comment: If I use ~ $(twentyChildElements).remove(); Will that work on the current content.

Comment: @RetroCoder: Sure, why wouldn't it? It removes all selected elements from their respective parent.

Comment: It works, but it leaves all the text nodes in between.  So I'm left which a ton of blank lines in between all the selectors.  Do you know how to remove all the innertext and all the selectors at the same time? "Text - Empty Text Node" 1000 of those.

Comment: Hm, since whitespace collapses this usually shouldn't matter. To remove them, you'd probably do a manual loop over the `.childNodes` of each `div` and remove those whose `.value` is only whitespace. To do it in one go, I can only think of using [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and a clever filter

Comment: I tried this:  $("div").children("span").filter("> :nth-child(-n+20)").replaceWith("");   I think the > symbol does the items and everything inbetween.  Like see go fancy below...

Comment: And it looks like slice is supported by older browsers too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
var twentyChildElements = $("div > span:lt(20)");
```

`>` means *immediate children*, and `:lt(2)` means the first 20 elements that match the selector (it's zero-based, so this returns elements 0 through 19).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:lt` approach:

```
$("div").children("span:lt(n)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Go fancy... Let css do the job! ;)

Use a negative `nth-child` combinator selector. [**MDN nth-child selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
var twentyChildElements = $("div > span:nth-child(-n+20)");
```